# Android Two threads Read/Write on the same socket

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, android-service

I'm trying to get working a Service that hosts a server, and whenever it receives data from it's one client it sends the data off to another server. Both of which are connected by a tcp socket that remains open indefinitely. I'm having trouble implementing single tcp sockets that both read and write correctly.

I'm receiving XML from both ends, and they're well defined. Some processing is done on the xml received and it needs to be added to a queue that handles it's order.

Ideally the connection going in either direction should remain open indefinitely.

But so far I'm seeing the Sockets just keep closing both this Service and the ServerCode are getting closed sockets and I'm not sure why.

Is there a way to establish connections to my two endpoints and keep the sockets open indefinitely?

```
public class routing extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "[RoutingService]";

    private final IBinder mBinder = new RoutingBinder();
    private final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor mRoutingThreadPool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);

    private boolean running = false;
    private URI serverAddress;
    private URI clientAddress;

    private Thread serverServiceThread = new ClientService();
    private Thread clientServiceThread = new ServerService();

    private PriorityBlockingQueue<String> clientQueue;
    private PriorityBlockingQueue<String> serverQueue;

    public void setClientAddress(URI testServer) {
        this.serverAddress = testServer;
        this.mRoutingThreadPool.remove(clientServiceThread);
        this.mRoutingThreadPool.scheduleWithFixedDelay(clientServiceThread, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public URI getServerAddress() {
        return serverAddress;
    }

    public void setServerAddress(URI testServer) {
        startRunning();
        this.serverAddress = testServer;
        this.mRoutingThreadPool.remove(serverServiceThread);
        this.mRoutingThreadPool.scheduleWithFixedDelay(serverServiceThread, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public void startRunning() {
        running = true;
    }

    public void stopRunning() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        serverQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>();
        clientQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopRunning();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        clientAddress = URI.create("127.0.0.1:8054");
        serverAddress = URI.create("192.168.2.1:7087");

        startRunning();
        setClientAddress(clientAddress);
        setServerAddress(serverAddress);

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    public class RoutingBinder extends Binder {
        public routing getService() {
            return routing.this;
        }
    }

    class ClientService extends Thread {
        private Socket socket;

        private Runnable ClientReader = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (socket != null && socket.isConnected()) {
                    try (InputStreamReader sr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())) {
                        StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
                        char[] buffer = new char[8192];
                        String content = "";
                        int read;
                        while ((read = sr.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                            serverQueue.add(new String(buffer));
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("clientReader", "Error in testReading Thread.", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        private Runnable ClientWriter = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (socket != null && socket.isConnected()) {
                    while (serverQueue != null && !serverQueue.isEmpty()) {
                        try (OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream()) {
                            String xml = serverQueue.poll();
                            os.write(xml.getBytes());
                            os.flush();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e("clientWriter", "Error in testReading Thread.", e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(clientAddress.getPort())) {
                try (Socket socket = server.accept()) {
                    socket.setSoTimeout(0);
                    Log.d("SOCKET", String.format("Local Port: %s. Remote Port: %s", socket.getLocalPort(), socket.getPort()));
                    this.socket = socket;
                    //Make the Threads
                    Thread reader = new Thread(ClientReader);
                    Thread writer = new Thread(ClientWriter);
                    //Start the Threads
                    reader.start();
                    writer.start();
                    //Start the Server
                    startRunning();
                    //Join on the Threads so this driver thread will wait until they finish.
                    reader.join();
                    writer.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            stopRunning();
        }
    }

    class ServerService extends Thread {
        private Socket socket;

        private Runnable ServerReader = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (socket != null && !socket.isClosed()) {
                    try (InputStreamReader sr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())) {
                        StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
                        char[] buffer = new char[8192];
                        String content = "";
                        int read;
                        while ((read = sr.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                            clientQueue.add(new String(buffer));
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("ServerReader", "Error in testReading Thread.", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        private Runnable ServerWriter = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (socket != null && socket.isConnected()) {
                    try (OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream()) {
                        while (clientQueue != null && !clientQueue.isEmpty()) {
                            String xml = clientQueue.poll();
                            os.write(xml.getBytes());
                            os.flush();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("ServerWriter", "Error in testReading Thread.", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (running) { //Service will keep spinning unti the testService ends the loop
                try (Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress.getHost(), serverAddress.getPort())) {
                    socket.setSoTimeout(0);
                    Log.d("SOCKET", String.format("Local test Port: %s. Remote test Port: %s", socket.getLocalPort(), socket.getPort()));
                    this.socket = socket;
                    //Make the Threads
                    final Thread writer = new Thread(ServerWriter);
                    final Thread reader = new Thread(ServerReader);
                    //Start the Threads
                    writer.start();
                    reader.start();
                    //Join on the Threads so this driver thread will wait until they finish.
                    writer.join();
                    reader.join();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Closing the input or output stream of a socket closes the other stream and the socket.

Comment: Where do you see in the code that OP is closing a stream?